# Problem with Firestore dependencies while exporting jar using Gradle

Tags: java, eclipse, firebase, gradle, google-cloud-firestore

I am building an app in eclipse using Gradle.
When I test the app by running from Eclipse, everything works just the way it should - however, when I try to export and run the .jar file, I get the following error:

```
Failed for: .\ServiceAccountKey.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/firebase/cloud/FirestoreClient
    at main.Main.getSuroviny(Main.java:105)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     com.google.firebase.cloud.FirestoreClient
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

My build.gradle file looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their     own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:5.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
    //dependency for using firebase database
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
    //dependency for email and password authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
    //dependency for cloud storage
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


// Include dependent libraries in archive.

jar {
  manifest { 
    attributes "Main-Class": "main.Main"
  }  

  from {
    configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
  }
}
```

I have double-checked all imports and implementations, everything seems to be correct based on information I managed to find in Firestore documentations.

Also, I already tried to play around with a few things, the error changes on the first firstore method it finds - Whether it is DocumentReference, FirestoreClient, or whatever else.

Thanks to anyone with any recomendation in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the error has been my mistake - My .jar didn't include Service key necessary to load an instance of Firestore (for some reason I expected eclipse to include it while exporting the runnable jar file, since I have checked the "Include resource files in package" option.

Therefore, I included the Service key JSON file in the same folder where my .jar file is, so I am able to read it based on the file's location.

It's not quite an elegant workaround, but for now, that's enough.